# C# Linq Query against sub list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class structure as below whereby I have a list of OrderItems and each item has a list of Discounts

```
public class Order
{
    public IList<OrderItem> OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public IList<Discount> Discounts = new List<Discount>();
}

public class Discount
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to get a list of all discounts with an IsActive flag of true, how would I do this in a Linq query?

Currently this is what I have but it is very ugly with 2 foreach statements that need to be removed.

```
IList<Discount> activeDiscounts = new List<Discount>();
        foreach (OrderItem item in order.OrderItems)
        {
            var aDiscounts = from discount in item.Discounts.AsEnumerable()
                    where discount.IsActive == true
                    select discount;
            foreach (Discount discount in aDiscounts)
            {
                activeDiscounts.Add(discount);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `how would I do this in a Linq query?` Yo may start by trying something and then asking a specific question here if you get stuck somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one line linq statement:

```
order.OrderItems.SelectMany(item => item.Discounts.Where(discount => discount.IsActive));
```